# correctly describing actions performed on and the states of the Rubik's cube

Tags: word-request

> Jack took my **solved** Rubik's cube, **destroyed** it and then **re-solved** it.

How should I put this sentence correctly in English? What I want to say is that Jack took my Rubik's cube when it was in such a state when each side of the cube was of one color. Then, he did a few rotations to each side (he didn't physically destroy or break the cube), after which there were many colors on each side. And then he applied his skills to bring the whole cube back to the original state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Rubik's cube is commonly said to have a solved state and scrambled states. "Re-solve", however,  does not sound correct.

A natural way to say the sentence would be:

"Jack took my solved Rubik's cube, **scrambled** it and then solved it again."